Should I ask for my wedding voucher?
A few years ago, my management organized a voucher contribution for one of the manager's wedding. We were not invited but each of us paid £30 to get her a voucher. I got married two weeks ago and my managers were aware of that, but I did not receive any gift. Should I ask where my gift is? I think it is not fair that we are contributing to managers' gifts, but we don't get anything back.

Was there any pressure from management to contribute to the  gift? Could be hard to know, of course, just the fact that management were aware who had contributed how much would create implied presssure. Not that it changes the fact that you can't expect to ask for a voucher, but it does change how sucky we think your management is.

What management treats employees like crap?  I've never heard of such a thing.

You removed important context in your last edit. Why?

edit rolled back, made no sense post-edit

Unless it is Company Policy that people get a voucher on their Wedding, as much as it might suck - I would not say anything.
Your question is phrased as if it is an entitlement that you are owed a voucher. Now, I can sympathize that if someone else got a voucher for the same thing, you would be upset if you did not receive one - and it is quite a crappy thing for Management to do.
But at the same time - it is not an Entitlement - and acting as if it were is rather... Entitled.
There can be a myriad of reasons why they have not done it - Inflation and cost of living springs to mind. It could be that the person who organized it was a very good friend of the person getting married etc.
It is common that when you have big life events (Marriage, Babies etc.) that the office might do a little whip-around - but I would never expect this to happen, I would be grateful if I received anything, but understanding if I did not.
Depending on your office size, I can imagine 30 pounds per person would be quite the tidy sum - and so I appreciate that not getting it must smart a little - but demanding gifts, IMO, is the height of crass behavior.

@Fe2O3 - I hear that, however that was 2+ years ago - there is a lot of factors that could impact here.

@Fe2O3 - Different Managers, different management, different Financial circumstances, changes in company policy etc. 2+ years is a long time in business.

I contributed when a collection was made to get a nice lunch for the administrative / secretarial staff. That's work-related. A wedding hopefully is not.

This is going to depend a lot on Culture.
In my culture, this would be career suicide and haunt you for a while. It would be considered petty and make you seem childish, you could have just not participated in the first place.
Most likely this is a "tradition" among management, as you pointed out, that can't/shouldn't be applied to everyone. Can you imagine the chaos it would create if for example for everyone's birthday you threw a party ? Maybe in a smaller company that would be okay, in corporate hell that's not practical.
In short, NO, you shouldn't ask for your gift cards as I doubt they are contractually obligated to give you those. If you were management, maybe you could argue some discrimination, and feeling left out.

This is why the medieval calendar ended up with about 4 feast days a week.

@HappyIdiot We yearn for the feasts.

@Or4ng3h4t Everyones? no... People in your work group? yes... Its more like the other manager was your managers friend... so they organized stuff for them.

It would be in poor taste if you (the person getting married) were to organize a voucher contribution for your wedding.
It would not however be crass if a close friend at work were to organize a voucher contribution for your wedding.

Hopefully you have some friends at work.

In my experience, this is an entirely unofficial practice, an opportunity for coworkers to contribute to a group gift for someone if they feel like doing so. There is no obligation to contribute, and unless someone takes the incentive to make it happen, it doesn't happen.
Yes, it would have been nice if your co-workers had done something similar. Apparently none of them thought of it. (Of course, if you got married before joining the company, there's no reason they should have thought of it.) And no, in most companies it wouldn't have been appropriate for your manager to organize this.
Sorry, but you just didn't luck out. Hopefully next time you have a major event where this is appropriate, you will have more people who think of celebrating or commiserating with you. For now, grumble only to yourself for a day or two, then drop it; carrying a grudge will harm you much more than anyone else.

Right, people often contribute to flowers or something when someone dies.

@Fe2O3 just don't rent George a tux for the funeral service.
